# How can I get a reference to the changed element using *Changed?

Tags: dart, dart-html

Here's my html:

```dart
<polymer-element name="my-textarea">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_textarea.css">
    <textarea value="{{val}}"></textarea>
    <p>Val is: {{val}}</p>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_textarea.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

Here's my dart:

```dart
@CustomTag('my-textarea')
class MyTextarea extends PolymerElement {
  @observable var val = "Hello, World";

  MyTextarea.created() : super.created() {}

  valChanged(oldValue, newValue) {
    print("okay!");
  }
}
```

Instead of printing "okay!" when the value of the textarea changes, I would like to print the selectionStart. This is a property of the HTML element, so I need a reference to it. How can I get that inside the valChanged function?

Answer (score 1):

If you add an ID to the `<textarea>`, you can access it from within your class like so: `$['my-textarea']`

With that reference, you can access any textarea property you want.

Answer (score 1):

The `valChanged` method doesn't provide a reference to the element which caused the change. This method is called no matter what caused the change of the value. If you have `val = 'xxx';` in your code somewhere `valChanged` is called as well, not only when `my-textarea` is changed.